# Gaze interaction not working when side loaded

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I have created a simple UWP app that uses "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Input.GazeInteraction". In the VS environment, the gaze interaction works well.  However, when I create a package and side load on another PC the gaze interaction does not work, no gaze cursor displayed, no reaction when looking at a button.

Eye Gaze device has been tested and calibrated on the client PC

App installs without error (Power Shell install)

App runs without error

App request permission to use eye gaze device

App recognizes that eye gaze device is attached so "GazeInput.IsDeviceAvailable" is working

Ideas, suggestions on why the gaze interaction is not working?

Answer (score 2):

The "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Input.GazeInteraction" library leverages eye tracking hardware support built into Windows 10 (as of the Fall Creators Update - Version 1709) that is used for the [Eye Control feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043921/windows-10-get-started-eye-control) in Windows 10.

If your uwp application references the GazeInteraction [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Input.GazeInteraction/)

gaze interaction should work in your application without the need to reference a Tobii Nuget Package or the Tobii sdk.

When you side load your application onto another PC that machine also needs to be running the Fall Creator's Update version or better of Windows 10.

The machine will also need to have current drivers for your hardware installed on it.

For Tobii eye trackers [go here](https://tobiigaming.com/getstarted/).

For EyeTech trackers [go here](https://www.eyetechds.com/microsoft-hid-support.html).

Besides rebooting your system, one other simple thing to try is unplugging your eye tracker from the USB port and then plugging it back in, which can force a reinitialization of communication with the eye tracker in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

All you checks appear to show a working eye tracker, other than you not receiving the actual tracking data. A couple of other things to check:

Is Windows' Eye Control feature working? That uses essentially the same library as is in the toolkit. You can enable Eye Control from Start->Settings->Ease of Access->Eye Control.

On the development machine you say the application works "in the VS environment." Does it work on that machine outside of Visual Studio?

I assume you have powered down the target machine and restarted from cold.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had lost a reference to a Tobii NuGet package. Not sure why the app worked without the reference in VS